# Is there a way to make HTML5 video fullscreen?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, fullscreen

Is there a way to play a video fullscreen using the HTML5 `<video>` tag?

And if this is not possible, does anybody know if there is a reason for this decision?

Comment: @MiffTheFox A modern browser HTML5 support feature checklist can be found here: http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/#html5-web-applications

Comment: ##World's First True HTML5 Fullscreen Video##
http://blog.jilion.com/2011/07/27/world-s-first-true-html5-fullscreen-video Also see: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:FullScreenAPI

Answer (score 117, accepted):

## 2020 answer

HTML 5 provides no way to make a video fullscreen, but the parallel [Fullscreen API](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/) *defines an API for elements to display themselves fullscreen*.

This can be applied to any element, including videos.

[Browser support](https://caniuse.com/fullscreen) is good, but Internet Explorer and Safari need prefixed versions.

An [external demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dorward/Lsj4o8da/1/) is provided as Stack Snippet sandboxing rules break it.

```
<div id="one">
    One
</div>

<div id="two">
    Two
</div>

<button>one</button>
<button>two</button>
```

---

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#one { background: yellow; }
#two { background: pink; }
```

---

```
addEventListener("click", event => {
    const btn = event.target;
    if (btn.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "button") return;
    const id = btn.textContent;
    const div = document.getElementById(id);
    if (div.requestFullscreen) 
        div.requestFullscreen();
    else if (div.webkitRequestFullscreen) 
        div.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    else if (div.msRequestFullScreen) 
      div.msRequestFullScreen();
});
```

---

## 2012 answer

HTML 5 provides no way to make a video fullscreen, but the parallel [Fullscreen specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/fullscreen/) supplies the `requestFullScreen` method which allows arbitrary elements (including `<video>` elements) to be made fullscreen.

It has [experimental support in a number of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen).

---

## 2009 answer

**Note: this has since been removed from the specification.**

From the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090423/video.html#video) (at the time of writing: June '09):

> User agents should not provide a
> public API to cause videos to be shown
> full-screen. A script, combined with a
> carefully crafted video file, could
> trick the user into thinking a
> system-modal dialog had been shown,
> and prompt the user for a password.
> There is also the danger of "mere"
> annoyance, with pages launching
> full-screen videos when links are
> clicked or pages navigated. Instead,
> user-agent specific interface features
> may be provided to easily allow the
> user to obtain a full-screen playback
> mode.

Browsers may provide a user interface, but shouldn't provide a programmable one.

Answer (score 76):

Most of the answers here are outdated.

It's now possible to bring any element into fullscreen using the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode), although it's still quite a mess because you can't just call `div.requestFullScreen()` in all browsers, but have to use browser specific prefixed methods.

I've created a simple wrapper [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js) that makes it easier to use the Fullscreen API.

Current browser support is:

- Chrome 15+
- Firefox 10+
- Safari 5.1+

Note that many mobile browsers don't seem to support a [full screen option yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen).

Comment: Its not working. Iframe1 has child iframe2 from iframe2 when full-screen is applied it does nothing.

Comment: @YumYumYum from readme: "If your page is inside an <iframe> you will need to add a allowfullscreen attribute (+ webkitallowfullscreen and mozallowfullscreen)."

Comment: The demo seems not to work with Android 4.3's default browser.

Comment: @SindreSorhus is this support mobile browses now??

Answer (score 32):

**Safari** supports it through `webkitEnterFullscreen`.

**Chrome** should support it since it's WebKit also, but errors out.

Chris Blizzard of **Firefox** said they're coming out with their own version of fullscreen which will allow any element to go to fullscreen. e.g. Canvas

Philip Jagenstedt of **Opera** says they'll support it in a later release.

Yes, the HTML5 video spec says not to support fullscreen, but since users want it, and every browser is going to support it, the spec will change.

Comment: This answer is outdated, see the answer by Sindre Sorhus (and then vote it up so that it overtakes these out of date answers)

Answer (score 18):

```
webkitEnterFullScreen();
```

This needs to be called on the video tag ele­ment, for example, to full­screen the first video tag on the page use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].webkitEnterFullscreen();
```

**Notice: this is outdated answer and no longer relevant.**

Comment: This answer is outdated, see the answer by Sindre Sorhus (and then vote it up so that it overtakes these out of date answers)

Comment: Working in Chrome or Chromium and in Node-Webkit!

Answer (score 10):

Many modern web browsers have implemented a FullScreen API that allows you to give full screen focus to certain HTML elements. This is really great for displaying interactive media like videos in a fully immersive environment.

To get the full screen button working you need to set up another event listener that will call the `requestFullScreen()` function when the button is clicked. To ensure that this will work across all supported browsers you are also going to need to check to see if the `requestFullScreen()` is available and fallback to the vendor prefixed versions (`mozRequestFullScreen` and `webkitRequestFullscreen`) if it is not.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.msRequestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```

Reference:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode
Reference:- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos

Answer (score 7):

From CSS

```
video {
    position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really fullscreen.

Comment: We need a dynamic full screen for a video player.

Answer (score 6):

I think that if we want to have a open way to view videos in our browsers without any closed source plugins (and all the security breaches that comes with the history of the flash plugin...). The  tag has to find a way to activate full screen.. We could handle it like flash does: to do fullscreen, it has to be activated by a left click with your mouse and nothing else, I mean it's not possible by ActionScript to launch fullscreen at the loading of a flash by example.

I hope I've been clear enough: After all, I'm only a french IT student, not an english poet :)

See Ya!

Answer (score 5):

A programmable way to do fullscreen is working now in both Firefox and Chrome (in their latest versions). The good news is that a spec has been draft here:

http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html

You will still have to deal with vendor prefixes for now but all the implementation details are being tracked in the MDN site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode

Answer (score 3):

You can change the width and height to be 100%, but it won't cover the browser chrome or the OS shell.

Design decision is because HTML lives inside the browser window. Flash plugins aren't inside the window, so they can go full screen.

This makes sense, otherwise you could make img tags that covered the shell, or make h1 tags so the whole screen was a letter.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to have fullscreen video in html 5. If you want to know reasons, you're lucky because the argument battle for fullscreen is fought right now. See [WHATWG mailing list](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2010-March/thread.html) and look for the word "video". I personally hope that they provide fullscreen API in HTML 5.

Comment: Big +1 for the link to that mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox 3.6 has a full screen option for HTML5 video's, right-click on the video and select 'full screen'.

The latest Webkit nightlies also support full screen HTML5 video, try the [Sublime player](http://jilion.com/sublime/video) with the latest nightly and hold Cmd / Ctrl while selecting the full screen option.

I guess Chrome / Opera will also support something like this. Hopefully IE9 will also support full screen HTML5 video.

Answer (score 3):

This is supported in WebKit via [webkitEnterFullscreen](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/reference/WebKitDOMRef/HTMLVideoElement_idl/Classes/HTMLVideoElement/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution would be to have to browser simply provide this option on the contextual menu. No need to have Javascript to do this, though I could see when it would be useful.

In the mean time an alternative solution would simply be to maximise the window (Javascript can provide screen dimensions) and then maximise the video within it. Give it a go and then simply see if the results are acceptable to your users.

Answer (score 2):

The complete solution:

```
    function bindFullscreen(video) {
            $(video).unbind('click').click(toggleFullScreen);
    }

    function toggleFullScreen() {
            if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
                    !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
                    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
                            document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
                    } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
                            document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
                    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
                    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
                    }
            } 
            else {
                    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                            document.exitFullscreen();
                    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                            document.msExitFullscreen();
                    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
                    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
                            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
                    }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 video does go fullscreen in the latest nightly build of Safari, though I'm not sure how it is technically accomplished.

Comment: Why the negative vote? Safari 5 has fullscreen in its native controls. (No API though! grrrr)

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Well what happens with HTML5 video is that you just put the `<video>` tag and the browser will give it's own UI, and thus the ability for full screen viewing. It really makes life much better on us users to not have to see the "art" some developer playing with Flash could make :) It also adds consistency to the platform, which is nice.

Answer (score -1):

As of Chrome 11.0.686.0 [dev channel](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) Chrome now has fullscreen video.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this if you tell to user to press F11(full screen for many browsers), and you put video on entire body of page.

Answer (score -1):

If none of these answers dont work (as they didnt for me)  you can set up two videos.  One for regular size and another for fullscreen size.  When you want to switch to fullscreen

1. Use javascript to set the fullscreen video's 'src' attribute to the smaller videos 'src' attribute
2. Set the video.currentTime on the fullscreen video to be the same as the small video.
3. Use css 'display:none' to hide the small video and display the big one with the via 'position:absolute' and 'z-index:1000' or something really high.

Answer (score -1):

If you have option to define your site as progressive web app (PWA), then there is also option to use `display: "fullscreen"` under [manifest.json](https://web.dev/add-manifest/#display). But this will only work if user adds/installs your webapp to home screen and opens it up from there.

Answer (score -2):

it's simple, all the problems can be solved like this,

1) have escape always take you out of fullscreen mode
    (this doesn't apply to manually entering fullscreen through f11)

2) temporarily display a small banner saying fullscreen video mode is entered (by the browser)

3) block fullscreen action by default, just like has been done for pop-ups and local database in html5 and location api and etc, etc.

i don't see any problems with this design. anyone think i missed anything?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.