# Simulate F11 with javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, fullscreen

How can I simulate <kbd>F11</kbd> (fullscreen not maximaze browser window) as with flash:
http://www.broculos.net/files/articles/FullscreenFlash/flashFullscreen.html ?

in flash: `fscommand("fullscreen", true )`

```
permadi.com/tutorial/flash9FullScreen/index.html
```

Thanks

**Update**

I found this:

```
var docElm = document.documentElement;

if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
    docElm.requestFullscreen();
} else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}

/* Exiting the full screen => showing the FULL SCREEN button */
if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
    document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
        if(!document.fullscreen) {
            // Do something
        }
    }, false);
} else  if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
        if(!document.mozFullScreen) {
            // Do something
        }
    }, false);
} else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
        if(!document.webkitIsFullScreen) {
            // Do something
        }
    }, false);
}
```

this only works (from what've seen) only on a button click. Can't do this on page load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with JavaScript. It was proposed for the HTML5 video API but was later [scrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055214/is-there-a-way-to-make-html5-video-fullscreen).

Comment: It's not scrapped, its under heavy consideration: http://www.mail-archive.com/whatwg@lists.whatwg.org/msg19915.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a very basic tutorial on Mozilla:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

Please note that as of this post this is "experimental technology".

```
function requestFullScreen(elt) {
    console.log("Requesting fullscreen for", elt);
    if (elt.requestFullscreen) {
        elt.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elt.msRequestFullscreen) {
        elt.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elt.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        elt.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elt.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        elt.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
        console.error("Fullscreen not available");
    }
}
```

I was able to test this out successfully with div, video and canvas elements. Here is the code in jsfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/luken/001834wn/ -- but note that *it does not actually work in jsfiddle* for some reason.