# Put browser full screen and refresh on button click (simulate F11) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, keypress

I went through more than 10 questions with same content but not to find a updated answer. (world of web is changing rapidly I guess). First thing is, is it possible to put current window full screen simulating F11 press on a user button click. also what is the best practice for doing it if I want the function to work in all major browsers (IE, FF, Chrome and Safari).

[How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

[Simulate F11 with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094205/simulate-f11-with-javascript)

[onclick go full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900701/onclick-go-full-screen)

including above links I went through lot of questions but had no susses. Its really helpful if someone can come up with an idea. Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: Not possible, the way you want it. The links you provided are as good as it gets. Alternative answer: Do NOT mess with my main browser window. Open a new one, please

Comment: It was possible earlier, isn't it? in this case I want to re-size the current window by offering the user go to full screen button.

Comment: It was never possible to remove chrome from current window. IE allows(allowed) to open a new window and kill the current window which is something I call Denial Of Service if you do that to my window. I STRONGLY prefer a new window or do it like Chrome does [here](http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: well. I'm referring to the functionality of F11 key. my button is just supposed to be a virtual F11 key.

Comment: like this? http://fiddle.jshell.net/WWFXW/6/show/light/
see the implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/WWFXW/6/
fsapi in first link of @ZaoTaoBao answer is very complete btw.

Keep in mind that browser support is quite limited at the moment. Also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

Comment: That is the Chrome/Safari thing I mentioned. It works quite like F11 @j03w why not add as answer?

Comment: Thanks, I works for going fulls screen, but i want to refresh on full screen. as soon as I refresh it full screen is gone. any idea to get rid of that.

Comment: you can try reloading the data using ajax

Comment: no luck there, want to do in in .js file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this can help you [example of full screen](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/fullscreen/) using the blog post [Native Fullscreen JavaScript API (plus jQuery plugin)](http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: no, I want entire page full screen when user press the goTofullScreen Button.

Comment: See the link I added. Safari and Chrome supports that

Comment: Thanks, This also works for going fulls screen, but i want to refresh on full screen. as soon as I refresh it full screen is gone. any idea to get rid of that.

Comment: @Vixed, nope, had to stop refreshing. this is an old question. There might be a new solution now. Good luck finding that.

Answer (score 1):

This question is possibly a duplicate of a question you linked to. 
The latest cross-browser solution is:

```
function requestFullScreen(elt) {
    console.log("Requesting fullscreen for", elt);
    if (elt.requestFullscreen) {
        elt.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elt.msRequestFullscreen) {
        elt.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elt.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        elt.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elt.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        elt.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
        console.error("Fullscreen not available");
    }
}
```

Please note that this is "experimental technology" as of this post. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25774837/1766230) and [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode) for more details.