# Is there a jQuery library that can display an image up front and full screen?

Tags: jquery, image, fullscreen

I know there are ways to view an image full screen in Flash, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it in Javascript. It would be really great if anyone knew of a jQuery library that could handle it for me.

UPDATE: Since its impossible to do true full screen w/out Flash let's just say to fill up the browser window.

Thanks for looking

Comment: It cannot be full screen to the extent that it goes out of the browser like flash can.

Comment: Updated to assume that doing true full screen is impossible w/out Flash. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't as that cannot be done with javascript/ccs.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055214/is-there-a-way-to-make-html5-video-fullscreen) to understand the reasoning behind the reasons to forbid this action.

Comment: Updated to assume that doing true full screen is impossible w/out Flash. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Fancybox plugin and set it such that when it opens the dimensions of the box are equal to the dimensions of the viewing window of the browser.

Fancybox - http://fancybox.net/home

Here's an example of a Fancybox that should do just that...

> $('a.picture').fancybox({
>      padding : 0,
>      margin : 0,
>      scrolling : 'no',
>      width : window.innerWidth,
>      height : window.innerHeight,
>      overlayShow : 'false',
>      hideOnContentClick : 'true',
>      titleShow : 'false',
>      showCloseButton : 'false'
>   });

Note - This is 'full screen' as far as it will take up the entire browser viewport, but not the user's entire actual screen like Flash does.

Answer (score 0):

I use this ..is easy to use and configure....

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/
 ... prettyPhoto jQuery plugin