# In Html page <video> tag I want to increase height But not increased

Tags: html, css

In Html page `<video>` tag, I want to increase height. Even-though I use `!important` style attribute.

I tried to increase the video height but it is not getting increased.

```css
video {
  height: 400px !important;
}

.div2 {
  height: 400px;
  background: #6f7a2a;
}
```

```html
<div class="row div2">
  <video autoplay muted loop style="width:360px !important;">
    <source src="video/Australia.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

[image: Here image normal hight]
[image: Here I tried to increase picture height but not increased]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full Screen HTML5 Video Background without JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949387/full-screen-html5-video-background-without-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try this, its working for me as per your question

css

```
.video-size {
height:500px; /* Height option for changing*/
width:360px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.video-size > video {
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

html

```
<div class="video-size">
<video autoplay muted loop>
<source src="video/Australia.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row div2" >
    <video autoplay muted loop width="360" height="400" >
    <source src="video/Australia.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Try doing like this .. remove style attribute and add attributes height and width as shown above

Comment: @SivaKumar REMOVE ALL OTHER VIDEO STYLING like style tag and `video{ height:400px !important  }` remove that and try

Answer (score 0):

use something like id or class

```css
#video_id {
  height: 400px !important;
  width: 360px !important;
}

.div2 {
  height: 400px;
  background: #6f7a2a;
}
```

```html
<div class="row div2">
  <video id="video_id" autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="video/Australia.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    
.div2
{
height: 400px;
background: #6f7a2a;
}
```

```html
<div class="row div2" >
 <video autoplay muted loop style="height:100%;" >
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform` to maintain aspect ratio. For example

```css
video {
  transform: scale(3);
  background: #6f7a2a;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="video/Australia.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```