# Image following a mouse on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to have an image follow the mouse around the canvas, which is fairly easy, but the catch is that I want my canvas to change with screen resolution (it is set using CSS to be 70vw).

When the resolution decreases and the window becomes smaller this means that using a normal method of using clientX doesn't work.
My code so far is this:

```
var mouseX = e.clientX/document.documentElement.clientWidth * 1920;
var mouseY = e.clientY/document.documentElement.clientHeight * 943;
```

This tries to convert the users clientX into the value it would be on a 1920x1080 monitor.
However, this isn't really accurate and doesn't work very well on even 1920x1080 monitors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas This will help you.

Comment: First, show how you declare your canvas.  Are you setting explicit dimensions on it?  The `width` and `height` attributes are different from the `width` and `height` style attributes.

Comment: @UllasHunka thank you that has helped a lot

Comment: @haco pleasure is all mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't scale the canvas using CSS in the way that you think. A canvas is basically a more advanced image. Scaling the canvas via CSS just stretches the canvas the same way an image would stretch. To change the canvas `height` and `width`, you need to change it's `height` and `width` attributes in the tag or via code. This will physically change the canvas to the size that you want without scaling and/or stretching.

That being said, we can use this to watch for window size changes and resize the canvas when the window changes.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight
})
```

With some basic math, we can calculate what a 70% width would be, it would be done like this

```
window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.7
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight
})
```

The next thing we need to do is get the local position of the mouse on the canvas, which can be done using `mousePosition - canvasOffset` like this

```
let x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft
let y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop
```

When all is said and done, we end up with something like this (To see it in action press run then click on `Full Page` and you will see the canvas resize):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

// Set the inital height and width of the canvas
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

  // Get the local x/y coordinates of the mouse on the canvas
  let x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft
  let y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop

  // Draw a dot where the mouse is
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
})

// Update the height and width when the window size changes
window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

In this example below, we use a canvas that is `70%` the width and height of the screen and center it with CSS. However, we never touch the `height/width` with `css` because it will mess up the canvas' coordinate system. This part is done with JavaScript.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

// Set the inital height and width of the canvas
canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.7
canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.7

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

  // Get the local x/y coordinates of the mouse on the canvas
  let x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft
  let y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop

  // Draw a dot where the mouse is
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
})

// Update the height and width when the window size changes
window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.7
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.7
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took my snippet from my answer to [create a full screen canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987655/how-to-make-canvas-100-fit-to-the-screen/46988305#46988305).

I added this for mouse movement:

```
let User = { x: 0, y: 0 };

//controles if the mouse is moving
window.addEventListener(
    "mousemove",
    e => {
        User.x = e.clientX;
        User.y = e.clientY;
    },
    false
);
```

Uncomment: `cvs.ctx.drawImage(image, User.x, User.y);` in the `ShowImage()` function to draw an image at the mouse x and y position.
Mind to replace the path of the image source: `image.src = "Your/Path/To/Image.png";`

```js
/**
 * @author RensvWalstijn. GitHub: https://github.com/RensvWalstijn
 * Sets the canvas properties.
 * @param {object} Cvs Give the html canvas Id.
 * @param {boolean} Fullscreen Change the canvas fullscreen default false.
 * @param {string} Dimension Change the canvas dimension default "2d".
 * @return {object}
 */
function NewCanvas(cvs, fullscreen, dimension) {
    if (!dimension) dimension = "2d";
    var ctx = cvs.getContext(dimension);
    if (fullscreen) {
        cvs.style.position = "fixed";
        cvs.style.left = cvs.x = 0;
        cvs.style.top = cvs.y = 0;
    } else {
        var rect = cvs.getBoundingClientRect();
        cvs.x = rect.left;
        cvs.y = rect.top;
    }
    cvs.ctx = ctx;
    cvs.dimension = dimension;
    cvs.fullscreen = fullscreen;
    return cvs;
}

/**
 * @author RensvWalstijn. GitHub: https://github.com/RensvWalstijn
 * Updates the canvas width and hight.
 * @param {object} Cvs NewCanvas() object.
 * @param {boolean} Clear Change the canvas clear default true.
 */
function UpdateCvs(cvs) {
    if (cvs.fullscreen) {
        //if the width is not the same resize the canvas width
        if (window.innerWidth != cvs.width) {
            cvs.width = window.innerWidth;
        }
        //if the height is not the same resize the canvas height
        if (window.innerHeight != cvs.height) {
            cvs.height = window.innerHeight;
        }
    } else {
        let rect = cvs.getBoundingClientRect();
        cvs.x = rect.left;
        cvs.y = rect.top;
    }
}

function ClearCvs(cvs) {
    if (cvs.dimension == "2d")
        // set fillRect to clearRect to clear all of the canvas
        // fillRect is used here to show the full canvas
        cvs.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
}

/**
 * @author RensvWalstijn. GitHub: https://github.com/RensvWalstijn
 * get html element by id.
 * @param {string} id give the html element id.
 * @return {object} document.getElementById(id);
 */
function GetId(id) { return document.getElementById(id) }

// To create your canvas object.
var canvas = NewCanvas(GetId("yourCanvasId"), true);

// If you want to update your canvas size use this:
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    UpdateCvs(canvas);
});

let User = { x: 0, y: 0 };

//controles if the mouse is moving
window.addEventListener(
  "mousemove",
  e => {
    User.x = e.clientX;
    User.y = e.clientY;
  },
  false
);

// Set it to current width
UpdateCvs(canvas);
ClearCvs(canvas);

// create an image
let image = new Image();
image.src = "Your/Path/To/Image.png";

function ShowImage(cvs) {
    // Use this line to draw your image.
    // cvs.ctx.drawImage(image, User.x, User.y);
    
    // Shows where your image will be drawn.
    cvs.ctx.clearRect(User.x, User.y, 100, 100);
}

function Update() {
    ClearCvs(canvas);
    ShowImage(canvas);
    // keeps it looping
    window.requestAnimationFrame(Update)
}

// Init the loop
Update();
```

```html
<canvas id="yourCanvasId"></canvas>
```