# Making canvas fullscreen using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fullscreen

So I was trying to make a fullscreen canvas for a HTML document using Javascript. I have researched on how to create fullscreen canvas and I found a method but it is not perfect fullscreen. There is extra on the sides the bottom which makes the scroll bar come up. The code that I used is:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
```

I found out that the bookmark that I have in my browser (Chrome) pushes the canvas and when I remove it doesn't overflow outside. Is there anyway where if I have a bookmark or don't it will always result in a fullscreen canvas with no extra from the sides and the bottom

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4037426/215552) to [HTML Canvas Full Screen](//stackoverflow.com/q/4037212) mentions using `overflow:hidden` to prevent that. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes that works, Sorry I'm still a beginner at HTML, CSS and Javascript

Answer (score 2):

`scrollHeight` and `scrollWidth` might help

```
canvas.width = document.body.scrollWidth
canvas.height = document.body.scrollHeight
```