# button to make the site full screen

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

hi

i am working on a web site and i need to create a button to make the browser full screen

like when i press "f11"

how can i do that using javascript ?

Comment: @richsage : Look at the answer below. I have already provided same link.

Comment: (similar) [Is there a way to make HTML5 video fullscreen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055214/is-there-a-way-to-make-html5-video-fullscreen) albeit there is [::webkitEnterFullScreen](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/50893)

Answer (score -1):

short answer : you can't, javascript is used to modify the page, not control the browser

long answer : maybe browsers have some kind of API you can access to do this, but this would be different for each one of them.