# Html5 Full screen video

Tags: html

Is there any way to do this? I wan to play video in full screen. Without browser. setting `width:100%; height:100%;` keep browser visible yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make HTML5 video fullscreen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055214/is-there-a-way-to-make-html5-video-fullscreen)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this yet. I wish they add a future like this in browsers.

EDIT:

**Now there is a [Full Screen API](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#api) for the web** You can **`requestFullscreen`** on an Video or Canvas element to ask user to give you permisions and make it full screen.

Let's consider this  element:

```
<video controls id="myvideo">
  <source src="somevideo.webm"></source>
  <source src="somevideo.mp4"></source>
</video>
```

We can put that video into fullscreen mode with script like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { 
  elem.msRequestFullscreen();
}
```

[Full documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode)

Comment: Also for Edge or IE browsers add: `else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {  elem.msRequestFullscreen();}`

Comment: @mohsen  how to remove default controls and keep custom ones on full screen ?

Comment: @aeid best way is to wrap the video and your controls in a div and fullscreen the div, here's a rough example: https://codepen.io/lagged/pen/ppZNeB

Comment: @dab, your video doesn't change size.

Answer (score 19):

From CSS

```
video {
    position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

All hail HTML5 *_*/\_

```
var videoElement = document.getElementById('videoId');    
videoElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a very simple way (3 lines of code) using the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) and [RequestFullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen) method that I used, which is compatible across all popular browsers:

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
var fullscreen = elem.webkitRequestFullscreen || elem.mozRequestFullScreen || elem.msRequestFullscreen;
fullscreen.call(elem); // bind the 'this' from the video object and instantiate the correct fullscreen method.
```

For browser compatibility: 
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen#Browser_compatibility) & [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with jQuery.

I have my video and controls in their own `<div>` like this:

```
<div id="videoPlayer" style="width:520px; -webkit-border-radius:10px; height:420px; background-color:white; position:relative; float:left; left:25px; top:55px;" align="center">

    <video controls width="500" height="400" style="background-color:black; margin-top:10px; -webkit-border-radius:10px;">
         <source src="videos/gin.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>

    <script>  
        video.removeAttribute('controls');  
    </script> 

    <div id="vidControls" style="position:relative; width:100%; height:50px; background-color:white; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:10px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">

         <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0">

             <tr>
                 <td width="100%" align="center" valign="middle" colspan="4"><input class="vidPos" type="range" value="0" step="0.1" style="width:500px;" /></td>
             </tr>

             <tr>
                 <td width="100%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="javascript:;" class="playVid">Play</a></td>
                 <td width="100%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="javascript:;" class="vol">Vol</a></td>
                 <td width="100%" align="left" valign="middle"><p class="timer"><strong>0:00</strong> / 0:00</p></td>
                 <td width="100%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="javascript:;" class="fullScreen">Full</a></td>
              </tr>

            </table>

         </div>

      </div>
```

And then my jQuery for the **.fullscreen** class is:

```
var fullscreen = 0;

$(".fullscreen").click(function(){
  if(fullscreen == 0){
    fullscreen = 1;
    $("video").appendTo('body');
    $("#vidControls").appendTo('body');
    $("video").css('position', 'absolute').css('width', '100%').css('height', '90%').css('margin', 0).css('margin-top', '5%').css('top', '0').css('left', '0').css('float', 'left').css('z-index', 600);
    $("#vidControls").css('position', 'absolute').css('bottom', '5%').css('width', '90%').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5)').css('float', 'none').css('left', '5%').css('z-index', 700).css('-webkit-border-radius', '10px');

}
else
    {

        fullscreen = 0;

        $("video").appendTo('#videoPlayer');
        $("#vidControls").appendTo('#videoPlayer');

        //change <video> css back to normal

        //change "#vidControls" css back to normal

    }

});
```

It needs a little cleaning up as I'm still working on it but that should work for most browsers as far as I can see.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use html5 video player which has full screen playback option.
This is a very good html5 player to have a look. 
http://sublimevideo.net/

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (vi_video[0].exitFullScreen) vi_video[0].exitFullScreen();
    else if (vi_video[0].webkitExitFullScreen) vi_video[0].webkitExitFullScreen();
    else if (vi_video[0].mozExitFullScreen) vi_video[0].mozExitFullScreen();
    else if (vi_video[0].oExitFullScreen) vi_video[0].oExitFullScreen();
    else if (vi_video[0].msExitFullScreen) vi_video[0].msExitFullScreen();
    else { vi_video.parent().append(vi_video.remove()); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add object-fit: cover to the style of video

```
<video controls style="object-fit: cover;" >
```