# Is it possible to make my video go full screen when the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-video

When I arrive on a page with a `video.mp4` on it, I would like to make the video full screen immediately. The same way I would press on a the full screen video button, but without clicking on it. Just by default if the page is loaded the video goes full screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7cs5.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039909/html5-full-screen-video

Comment: For security reasons, you can't.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers ! @QuentinVeron what are the security reasons about a fullscreen video ? I try to understand. Thanks