# How to make a video fill the available viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a video embedded on an HTML page like this:

```
<div id="contentVideo">
  <video id="video" controls autoplay preload="auto" type="video/mp4" src=<?php echo $url; ?>">
</div>
```

and this CSS

```
#video {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

I have tried also

```
#video {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

This video's data is read by PHP and dumped on the page, so the user will not see the video's URL.

That works fine, except for two problems:

1. The video will not autoplay on safari
2. The video fills a gigantic size but I want it to fill just the size of the browser.

I explain: the video is HD. Suppose the user is seen that page on a browser window that has no more of 1000x500 pixels. I want the video to scale to fit on the available window, not to display at its original size.

How do I do that with CSS/JavaScript keeping the video proportion, in a way that the video rescales if the window changes size?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Html5 Full screen video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039909/html5-full-screen-video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to resolve this by using media query using css.  here is the point. you should set the # media-container in whatever sizes you want it to look like. with the media query s I have provided, you can set which #media-container should look like what size. you can also use `object-fit : cover;`. So you can get a video that is responsive by size.

```
 // Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
}

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {

 }

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }
```

also, if you want to adjust the size for the video container and always show the size of the video you put in it, you might be interested in this feature. : Aspect ratio container : https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/

note: it doesn't seem like you need to use javascript for this situation.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question, I'll link similiar question on stackoverflow: [Video auto play is not working in Safari and Chrome desktop browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994666/video-auto-play-is-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome-desktop-browser) - you have to add muted attribute to video

Second part: you can use CSS property `object-fit: cover` on your video element (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) - works in all modern browsers except for IE (so it works in all modern browsers). So your css should look like:

```
#video {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: `object-fit` not working for me. Unfortunately I cannot have the video muted. The problem is that it autoplays with audio on chrome.

Comment: Please post an example somewhere (JsFiddle/JsBin)?

Comment: It will not autoplay on Chrome mobile, or any mobile device without the muted tag.

On Chrome desktop - there are customer specific semantics that dictate autoplay (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). make sure it plays in an incognito tab (or another device running Chrome).  Juts having pressed play inthe past on your page is enough for it to autoplay.