# Replicate no "playsinline" video attribute on Android devices?

Tags: android, html, web, mobile, html5-video

Without the [`playsinline`](https://css-tricks.com/what-does-playsinline-mean-in-web-video/) attribute, videos will automatically go full screen when the video play button is pressed on iOS devices. I might need this full screen only behavior in the future.

Like I mentioned, iOS devices will go full screen without the `playsinline` attribute. However, Android devices can play the video minimized without the attribute. Is there a simple way to replicate this behavior in android? Or should I resort to JavaScript?

Comment: Resort to Javascript in both cases for a future-proof solution (default behaviour of `playsinline`on iOS might change in the future).

Comment: @VC.One Ah, good thinking. I totally overlooked that aspect. Thank you!

Comment: You want this API  for your `<video>` when a user presses the custom play button : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6039930/2057709