# HTML5: Placing a canvas on a video with controls

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-canvas

I want to draw things on HTML5 video. For that I am trying to place a canvas on the HTML5 video element.

But there is a problem when I place the canvas on the video element the video controls do not work. Since canvas getting all the mouseover and click events. Is there a way to delegate the events to video controls or show the controls in somewhere else?

Any help/idea would be great.

Comment: Perhaps you want it the other way round: drawing the video on canvas and enhance it with fancy stuff and interaction there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is implement your own controls (or use an existing set such as [videojs](http://videojs.com/))
You can read my answer to this question: [Html5 video overlay architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402527/html5-video-overlay-architecture/6402587#6402587)

Comment: This seems like overkill. Even if the asker wants the canvas to stillbe able to receive events, it should still be possible to conditionally re-route events to the video element as they have wondered.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the click events in the canvas and calculate their position. Based on that, you could approximate which control was targeted and make the video changes your self.
I mean something like this :

```
canvas.onclick = function(e){
    if(isOverPauseBtn(e))
        video.pause();
    //.. and so on
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase the z-index of canvas. `z-index=10`
Bring the video under the canvas. 
Height of canvas = height of entire video - height of video controls.

You can cover only the video part with canvas and if hover on the bottom of the canvas, you will get the controls

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the canvas to receive *any* pointer events, then you can use  the [CSS `pointer-events` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the canvas and set it to `none`.