# Embedded HTML5 & Jquery marquee

Tags: jquery, html, embed, html5-video, marquee

i need to embed an html5 video with a ticker marquee jquery. All into the video.

Have some idea?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Be specific... what are you trying to do?  What is your question?

Comment: Do we 'have some idea' about *what*?

Comment: I need to do a video player with a ticker message. I do player with html5 and i use jquery marqee for ticker. I need to embed this two conponent in only one, but i have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the solution is using z-index in html! It work!!

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

'embed this two conponent in only one' are you talking about html overlays?! if so check here [HTML5: Placing a canvas on a video with controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511319/html5-placing-a-canvas-on-a-video-with-controls) and here [Html5 video overlay architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402527/html5-video-overlay-architecture)

if not, check Brads idea: be specific! the more information you share, the better answer you'll get!

Comment: I would like to do a page like this (http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/28/immaginecoc.jpg/) So it is more clear?

Thaks to all!