# Can I make a full-screen HTML5 game?

Tags: html, fullscreen

I'm making an HTML5 game.

Is there anyway to provide the user with a button to make it full-screen? For any browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure how the "quality standards" quote is relevant here. If your users want to view your HTML5 application in full-screen mode, they only need to press F11 (Windows) or choose the View->Fullscreen option in their browser's menu.

Comment: May help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055214/is-there-a-way-to-make-html5-video-fullscreen

Comment: You'll get a better response if you reword the question to be more constructive.

Comment: The problem is that flash games have a fullscreen button, but html5 games do that. That makes HTML5 apps second class citizens.

Comment: But it does seem impossible or else someone would've answered.

Comment: “The problem is that flash games have a fullscreen button, but html5 games do that. That makes HTML5 apps second class citizens.” — I think allowing full-screen mode can be a bit of a security issue. Someone could write full-screen content that imitates the website the user is on, and tricks them into entering password details.

Comment: The browser can add some sort of control, like the desktop notifications permissions dialog.

Comment: For Safari on a Mac you at least have to wait till Lion and even then there are bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is yes:

Webkit fullscreen api seems like it's coming.

http://peter.sh/2011/01/javascript-full-screen-api-navigation-timing-and-repeating-css-gradients/

Very cool.

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla, Chrome and Safari now have a Javascript API to make an element full screen.

What one does to make an element full screen, is:

`document.getElementById("myvideo").requestFullScreen()`

http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: WebKit has an [experimental implementation of fullscreen](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/50893), but only for the video element.  Mozilla is looking at doing [a spec where any element can be made full screen](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko%3aFullScreenAPI) ([see also](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-fx/2011JanMar/0060.html)), but no formal spec document has yet been produced, and there are no implementations.

Edit:

Just a note, experimental implementations of the Full Screen API are [now available in everything except IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode).

Comment: Well a video could be generated by JavaScript on the fly but this is not really the way OP though of I guess. :)