# Displaying video on webpage

Tags: html, asp.net-webpages, webmatrix-2

I'm working on a website and I want to display video on the home page.
Although I have achieved this using embed tag and .swf format.

But the problem is as soon as the page is loaded the video begins. I want the video to show play, pause and full screen features. I'm not able to display video controls any other format (using google chrome). Can anyone guide me, I have gone through a number of websites providing code for this but hadn't achieve the above features.

Comment: you could use flowplayer

Answer (score 1):

Try http://flowplayer.org/

It's a cool flash player plugin, with all the features you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Html-5 we have an video tag. [for further details  see here](http://w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp)

But the Full Screen mode view option is not supported by all browsers.
The reason for this is explained in this post [Is there a way to make HTML5 video full screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055214/is-there-a-way-to-make-html5-video-fullscreen)