# Can't enter fullscreen in MediaElement

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I have MediaElement running an embedded youtube, within a slideshow.  The video player and controlbar are working perfectly, but it won't go fullscreen.  I hit the button and nothing happens!  any ideas?

here is the test page: http://prmot.it/cms/node/13

Answer (score 0):

that video played with HTML5 video tag, to make it full screen check this

[Is there a way to make HTML5 video fullscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055214/is-there-a-way-to-make-html5-video-fullscreen)

Comment: That might make sense, except that it works in my stand-alone POC here: http://prmot.it/cms/themes/prmotittheme/jscarousel/

MediaElement.js provides for fullscreen using requestfullscreen, where available, and a flash or silverlight fallback, where not.

It looks more like the button press is never registering.