# HTML5 video override fullscreen control

Tags: javascript, html, video

Is it possible to intercept and override the functionality when a user clicks on the fullscreen button built into the default HTML5 video player?

Background - I have a video player with a custom overlay (not custom controls, though) and I need to still display that overlay in fullscreen mode. I can add my own button to the screen that makes the player fullscreen and still displays my overlay, but I would like to somehow bind this functionality to the built-in fullscreen button in the player controls so I can still use those controls and provide fullscreen support. Thanks!

Comment: see similar post
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415536/html5-fullscreen-video-onclick-event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415536/html5-fullscreen-video-onclick-event)

Comment: [fullscreenchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/fullscreenchange) maybe.

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't able to test this without an example video or audio file, but the following should allow you to track the `fullscreenchange` event and the associated `document.fullscreenElement` across browsers ([they are all behind vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#Prefixing) at this point).

```js
var fullscreen = getFullscreenProps(),
    video = document.querySelector('video')

console.log(fullscreen)

document.addEventListener(fullscreen.fullscreenchange, function (event) {
  var isVideoFullscreen = document[fullscreen.fullscreenElement] === video
  console.log(isVideoFullscreen)
})


function getFullscreenProps () {
    var keys = 'fullscreenElement mozFullScreenElement msFullscreenElement webkitFullscreenElement'.split(' '),
        prefixes = ' moz ms webkit'.split(' ')
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (keys[i] in document) {
            return {
              fullscreenElement: keys[i],
              fullscreenchange: prefixes[i] + 'fullscreenchange'
            }
        }
    }
    return {
        fullscreenElement: keys[0],
        fullscreenchange: 'fullscreenchange'
    }
}
```

```html
<video src="http://example.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="100" height="100"/>
```