# Element not filling in container?

Tags: html, css

I have a div as a container for a video element, I want the video element to fill the **entire container**, to do this I set the background color of the div to black and the height and width of the video to 100%. **I am still seeing black**, how do I get the video to fill the entire container? **It fills the entire width, but not the height.**

```css
#videoContainer{

width: 600px;
height: 600px;
background-color: black;

}

#video{


  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div id ="videoContainer">
 <video  id="video">

    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">

 </video>
</div>
```

Comment: you should set the height to 600px

Comment: videos are usually a ratio in this case the video is a 4:3 ratio and you are trying to fit it into a 1:1 ratio which will not work. You can try using object-fit https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp this however will crop some of the video and has partial support https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Comment: Or you should set only one of height and width. So, that the un-mentioned can scale to the child element's(in your case: image) size.

Comment: I tried setting the size to 600px, I still see black

Comment: @GingerCSSWizard So how does YouTube do it then? When I inspect the page of a YouTube video, the video fills the entire `div` YouTube put the video element in?

Comment: @user987938 Youtube does it by letting the video determine the height and not forcing fixed values on the containing div. Also you will notice that youtube videos usually when in cinema mode have black borders. The standard aspect ratio for youtube videos is 16:9 and the majority of screens nowadays are 16:9 so the video fits nicely when in fullscreen mode.

Comment: @GingerCSSWizard So if I want to do it like YouTube does it, I just need to omit the `height` from the `video` id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments the below will make the video fill the containing div.

If you are looking to make the video fit the users screen take a look at this related post [Is there a way to make HTML5 video fullscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055214/is-there-a-way-to-make-html5-video-fullscreen)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#videoContainer {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}

#video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="videoContainer">
  <video id="video">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

over-ride the default `object-fit` css property from `contain` to `cover`

```css
#videoContainer{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: black;
}
#video{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id ="videoContainer">
  <video id="video">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes the video element spill out of the div